# How to add an onload eventListener to a popup in Opera

Tags: javascript, dom-events, opera

I'm writing an application that needs to call a function when a popup has loaded. Currently, this is what I'm using, which works in Firefox/Chrome/Safari:

```
var win = window.open(...);
win.addEventListener( 'load', function () {...}, true );
```

However, opera does not like `win.addEventListener`. I tried `win.opera.addEventListener` too, but that also didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting the onload event of a window opened with window.open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open)

Comment: win.on('load', function(){
}

Have you tried this

Comment: known bug: `CORE-46278` at Opera. See also [Opera: Can't get load event from window.open()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499709/opera-cant-get-load-event-from-window-open)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499709/opera-cant-get-load-event-from-window-open) which had been found previously

```
var openedWindow = window.open("test.html", "title");

window.setTimeout(function() {
    openedWindow.addEventListener("load", function() {
        console.log("received load event");
    }, false);
}, 0);
```