# onload() in pop up window is not working in opera

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ckeditor, opera

When I try to do anything in `onload()` function of pop up window, it doesn't show up in `opera`. But it is working fine in all other browsers.

In the below code, I was trying to fill a `div` in the pop up on `onload`.

```
<script>
var title=$('#title').val();
var content=CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData();
var popup = window.open("<?php echo site_url('/index'); ?>",'pop up','width=1100,height=600,scrollbars=1');

popup.onload = function(){
    $('#content', popup.document).html(content);
    $('.title', popup.document).html(title);
}
</script>
```

Can anyone please tell me any solution?

Comment: Please take a quick look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499709/opera-cant-get-load-event-from-window-open), seems it's a known bug.

Comment: Why not you put the onload code on the view selected by `/index` controller?

Comment: The view in the /index controller is used by other end.so i cant include onload code in that.i wanted to display that same view in the pop up in other end.